# How to get/pass dynamic controls in $.post method in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, dynamic-controls, request.form

I am add controls dynamically in my page from the database and i am using $.post() method to pass values in client side. Now i want to pass this controls in $.post() method.
so can any one suggest me how to get these controls in post method.

```
 $.post("TestPage.aspx", { Type: 'SaveData', drpGender: $('#MainContent_drpGender').val(), cmbMonth: $('#MainContent_cmbMonth').val(), cmbYear: $('#MainContent_cmbYear').val(), drpTall: $('#MainContent_drpTall').val(), txtWeight: $('#MainContent_txtWeight').val() }, function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }, "html");
```

in above, drpGender, cmbMonth,drpTall,txtheigh are dynamic controls which i add in my page.

In client side , i am saving data in SaveData() method. and i am using this controls value client side by using

```
Request.Form["drpGender"];
```

So can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.Form` is not populating for your Ajax post because you are manually serializing and sending the data to the controller as a JSON object, not as Form encoded data.

Try URL encoding your object before sending with $.post.  I split some of the code up for readability - you can just add the `$.param()` call inline if you want.

```
// Get your submit data.
var sendData = { Type: 'SaveData', drpGender: $('#MainContent_drpGender').val(), cmbMonth: $('#MainContent_cmbMonth').val(), cmbYear: $('#MainContent_cmbYear').val(), drpTall: $('#MainContent_drpTall').val(), txtWeight: $('#MainContent_txtWeight').val() };

// Form encode your data.
sendData = $.param(sendData);

// Send.
$.post("TestPage.aspx", sendData, function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }, "html");
```

This will cause the controller to treat the received request like a Form post and populate `Request.Form`.